# "No provider error" on Karma serve running angularjs phonecat tutorial

Tags: angularjs, module, karma-runner

I have found and tried many solutions offered here and elsewhere: re downgrading karma version upgrading node and npm - changing order of load in the config file....
but so far nothing works.  Is the problem that I am running the angular tutorial via Apache?

### Starting Karma Server (http://karma-runner.github.io)

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:9
      throw error('No provider for "' + name + '"!');
            ^
Error: No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine)
    at error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:22:68)
    at Object.parent.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:9:13)
    at get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:54:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:28:14
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:27:21)
    at invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
    at Object.exports.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:204:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/bin/karma
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:9
      throw error('No provider for "' + name + '"!');
            ^
Error: No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine)
    at error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:22:68)
    at Object.parent.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:9:13)
    at get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:54:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:28:14
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:27:21)
    at invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
    at Object.exports.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:204:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/bin/karma:19:39)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421857/error-no-provider-for-frameworkjasmine-resolving-frameworkjasmine)

Answer (score 32):

You have to install jasmine:

```
    npm install -g karma-jasmine
```

Comment: and by default, it also looks for the 'karma-chrome-launcher' - https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher

Answer (score 15):

The selected answer didn´t work for me, this is what it work for me:

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/880

> Karma needs to load the plugins (such as karma-jasmine). By default
>   (if you don't specify config.plugins), Karma loads all the karma-*
>   modules that are siblings to Karma.
>
> It sounds like you have Karma installed globally (npm install -g
>   karma) and jasmine plugin locally (npm install karma-jasmine). If
>   that's the case, install Karma locally.
>
> The recomended way is to install Karma and all the plugins locally,
>   per project.

Answer (score 9):

as per the documentation following plugins are required.
  // these plugins will be require() by Karma
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-chrome-launcher'

So add these two to your plugin section.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what platform/os/version you're on, but for me, on mac os x 10.9 ("Mavericks"), I  was running into the exact same issue with trying to run karma on an e2e test with the simple angular docs tutorial in their step 3. I solved it in a pretty silly/dumb way =>

1. Closed the terminal/shell window in which I had all these problems
2. Re-opened a new terminal/shell window
3. Ran everything with `sudo` in front

It all installed/worked, including... `npm install -g`.

so there you go.

Comment: You should not ever use `sudo` to install npm packages