# Error: No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine)

Tags: npm, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have run on my windows console:

```
npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower

npm install -g generator-angular

yo angular
```

Then I started my project with webstorm and did right click on the karma.conf.js file in the project explorer where I have the menu item 'Run karma.conf.js' and start the karma runner. Then I get his exception:

```
...\app\node_modules\karma\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:9
      throw error('No provider for "' + name + '"!');
            ^
Error: No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine)
```

Then in the console I read I can also use --force so I tried it: grunt --force

It took some time but there seemed to be no more errors. Heck why does --force install a provider ??? THIS was TESTED in the CMD.

grunt serve now worked and it started my browser with the starting app.

**So what was --force doing that the 'Error: No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine)' is gone ?**

When I do grunt in the webstrom IDE I get again:

Warning: No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine) Use --force to continue.

So this problem is not solved.

Comment: @Sergio we've created a good answer upvoted below. Should this be the accepted answer?

Comment: @grant your answer sure seems to be appreciated by the community. Only the author of the question can accept the answer if it solved the specific problem. Congrats on your 1k btw!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367059/no-provider-for-frameworkjasmine-resolving-frameworkjasmine)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Grunt --force works because you tell it to bypass the karma tests. Notice if you run grunt --force, it'll still say "Done, but with warnings".

To fix:
add "karma-jasmine" and "karma-chrome-launcher" (or whatever launcher you use) to the devDependencies in packages.json and run npm install again.

```
npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev

npm install karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev
```

This will save karma-jasmine and karma-chrome-launcher in your project's package.json file. The packages can then be installed by running:

```
npm install
```

Source: [No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367059/no-provider-for-frameworkjasmine-resolving-frameworkjasmine)

Comment: I was having the same problem as Sergio, and this solution worked for me. I ran those two commands, then `npm install` and I could then run `karma start karma.conf.js` without any errors

Comment: @ColeGarstin thank you, glad it worked out. This is a great point. Running these commands will save the karma-jasmine and karma-chrome-launcher packages in your project's package.json file which can be installed through npm install.

Comment: I'm new to nodejs. When you say `your project's package.json` do you mean my projects source folder or `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` or something else?

Comment: @NicholasTolleyCottrell typically any project built with grunt has a package.json file in the root directory of the project. This is what determines which packages are installed into node_modules through npm and can be used to track dev dependencies of the project.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Thank you. Any reason why this is not the accepted answer ?

Comment: @axesdenied great to hear. I commented in the original post, hopefully someone accepts it.

Answer (score 75):

for me I didn't have the karma client installed globally.

`npm install -g karma-cli`

Comment: This answer combined with grant's answer solved my problem.

Comment: Same as @Lothre1.

Comment: removing plugins section from karma.conf solved for me

Comment: nope also didnt help.

Answer (score 16):

And for those who are still new enough to Karma (like me), don't forget to make sure you've added the plugin to your karma.conf.js file.  Finally occurred to me after running through most of these other proposed fixes : (

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',

    plugins: [
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine'
    ],
...
```

Hope this helps someone out there, even though this question is now pretty ancient and doesn't seem the originator is still monitoring it ; )

Comment: did this too,doesnt work

Answer (score 10):

Adding a reply in case if someone **still** gets this error.

Karma-cli (`karma start`) will give 
**Error: No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine)** for one of the following reasons:

1. You have not yet installed karma-jasmine node module and its not listed in devDependencies section in your package.json

**Solution**: `npm install -D karma-jasmine`

2. You have a 'plugins' property array in your karma.config.js file, but this array has no mention of 'karma-jasmine'.

**Solution**: Add 'karma-jasmine' to  plugins in karma.config.js or get rid of this whole 'plugins' property if possible.

`plugins:['karma-jasmine']`

3. You have a global install of 'karma-cli' and when you do `'karma start'`, karma is trying to find the karma-jasmine module in global scope.
   Check global installed modules list using: `npm list -g --depth=0`.

**Solution**: Either install karma-jasmine also in global scope using `'npm install -g karma-jasmine'` or remove karma from global scope and install it in local project scope. In later case you will have to add following to package.json:

```
"scripts" { 
 "test": "karma start"
}
```

and run karma using command `'npm run test'` or `'npm test'`.

Comment: nope, didnt work

Answer (score 7):

I struggled with the exact same problem. After investigating I realized that karma was running globally using '/usr/' directory as the base folder.

A solution that worked for me was to replace karma with karma-cli:

```
npm remove -g karma
npm install -g karma-cli
```

Comment: This left me with the error message "You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!" after starting karma.

Comment: nope, didnt work

Answer (score 1):

For those of you using karma-spec-reporter and getting this error: 
"Error: No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine)"

In your karma.conf.js, remove: "plugins: ["karma-spec-reporter"]" and the error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the primary bug request on github
https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/629

According to this, the problem is more with the karma-generator in which used to contain these 2 extensions by default and no longer do.

Answer (score 0):

And for me, I didn't have the karma-jasmine globally.

```
npm install -g karma-jasmine
```

as described here: ["No provider error" on Karma serve running angularjs phonecat tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185548/no-provider-error-on-karma-serve-running-angularjs-phonecat-tutorial)

Answer (score -1):

npm i -D @types/es6-promise @types/es6-collections

Answer (score -1):

Another way that could correct the problem as it did for me is:

1. Install `karma-jasmine-dom` with this command line `npm install karma-jasmine-dom --save-dev`
2. Add these lines in karma.conf.js file:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'jasmine-dom'],
    ...
    plugins: [
      ...
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-jasmine-dom',
      ...
    ]
    ...
  })
}
```

Then when I run `karma start`, the error doesn't appear anymore.

Hope it helped

Comment: does not. repeated answer anyways.